# I have to restart the rails server each time i load a new image. How do i load and render images dynamically without restarting the server.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used the assets pipeline to load the images. during runtime i try to load a new image and render it. But it gives the error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fop5l.png)

When i restart the server, the new image is rendered. Please help me out with a way to render images dynamically without restarting the server.

Comment: Why r u running the server in Production ?

Answer (score 0):

Your image is not in `app/assets/images` so the Rails asset pipeline isn't able to find it.

Also make sure you're running in development mode with `RAILS_ENV=development rails s`

And in your `development.rb` configuration ensure the following:

- `config.assets.enabled = true`
- `config.assets.compile = true`
- `config.consider_all_requests_local = true`
- `config.action_controller.perform_caching = false`
- `config.cache_classes = false`

Perhaps most importantly, it looks like you're storing separate images for each user? This isn't something you'd want to use the asset pipeline for. User uploaded and generated content should generally go in a cloud storage service such as Amazon S3. I'd recommend looking into using Carrierwave with Fog to handle image uploads.

Comment: My images are there in app/assets/images .